# prevent css from getting overriden

Tags: html, css, asp.net, telerik

I have asp.net web forms project where I am using telerik controls.

> My issue

At one place I need to load html data from database, it contains lots of css, images and html.

Here is my code.

```
<telerik:RadLabel ID="ProdDetails" runat="server" Text='<%# (HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)Eval("HtmlBody"))) %>'></telerik:RadLabel>
```

It works fine, **but some times this database html css overrides site css and becuase of that site become unstable.**

So, **is there any that my site css can't be override by incoming html.**

> before down vote or close vote, please let me know if there is anything missing, wrong or required..

Comment: are you allowing arbitrary user-generated HTML and CSS to be rendered? Risky in lots of ways. If it happens to override yours, that's probably just bad luck. You could consider just re-naming all your standard CSS classes etc which a prefix which other code is unlikely to use.

Comment: yes, I am loading amazon prints and they contains lots of css, I don't know what to change becase it's not fix which css get override.

Comment: in that case change everything you've got. If your app is called "showpicturesapp" then maybe prefix all your CSS classes and IDs with "show-pictures-app-" so there's little to no chance that CSS from elsewhere will have the same classes. That's not to say it can't still override specific _properties_ by putting !important next to them etc, but hopefully the prefixing means they won't get applied to the same elements and will not be an issue.

Comment: I was thinking on use of Iframes

Comment: Yeah that's worth a go, might be simpler, assuming there's no particular interaction required between this custom HTML and your main page.

Comment: @ADyson it worked perfectly..

Comment: In that case post it as the answer, you are allowed to answer your own question and accept the answer. Then anyone with this problem in future will clearly see a solution which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, the question is bit of in wrong way but in general practice anyone get this kind of issue.

So, After wasting a full day in finding proper way to handle it, at last I found something that doesn't need to update site css or any other part.

It's a **iframe**.

yes, instead of rendering html in div or any other element render it in **iframe**

see the work around I have did for me.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" 
  height="400px"  runat="server" id="test" 
  srcdoc='<%# (HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)Eval("HtmlBody"))) %>'>
</iframe>
```